# Want to build bare Linux system that has only a kernel and one binary

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, hardware

I want to build a dedicated Linux system that only ever runs one binary program. This program takes control of the screen via the OpenGL driver and displays patterns. There needs to be keyboard input as well to configure the patterns. Since running this one program will be the sole purpose of the machine, I don't need any GUI, networking, etc. Also, I probably don't need any process scheduling in the kernel since only one process will ever run.

Is it possible to replace /sbin/init with my own binary to achieve this? After the kernel loads, it would then immediately execute my own binary, and that would run the entire time the machine was on. Basically, I want to emulate the way a microcontroller works, but with the benefit of being able to use an x86 CPU with different hardware devices and drivers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be possible to replace `/sbin/init`  by your program, but you should be aware that process 1 has some specific duties. So I think it is not advisable to replace it.

Remember that a Linux kernel can also start some processes magically, outside of the usual `fork` from a process inherited by the init process. I'm thinking of things  like `/sbin/modprobe`  or `/sbin/hotplug`  etc.

Also, `udev` (or `systemd`) have some special roles. On some systems, fan control was related to such things (I really forgot the details).  If unlucky, you could burn your hardware if fan is not working well (but AFAIK this is no more true on recent hardware).

By seeking with `string`  the `vmlinux`  in a recent 3.15.3 kernel, I find that it knows about:

- /bin/init
- /bin/sh
- /sbin/request-key
- /sbin/tomoyo-init
- /sbin/modprobe
- /sbin/poweroff
- /sbin/hotplug

I would recommend instead keeping some existing init program, and configure it to run only your program.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose I could handle these duties in my own program, assuming they don't interfere with its operation. I could also disable module loading, etc. or any other kernel feature that would require support from init.

Comment: Some other things that come to mind are *hotplug* support and *module loading*.  The kernel occasionally calls *user space* helpers, depending on the configuration and version.  You will need a statically populated */dev/* directory, etc.  Your program can of course `fork()` others.

Answer (score 7):

**Minimal init hello world program step-by-step**

[image]

Compile a hello world without any dependencies that ends in an infinite loop. `init.S`:

```
.global _start
_start:
    mov $1, %rax
    mov $1, %rdi
    mov $message, %rsi
    mov $message_len, %rdx
    syscall
    jmp .
    message: .ascii "FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR\n"
    .equ message_len, . - message
```

We cannot use `sys_exit`, or else the kernel panics.

Then:

```
mkdir d
as --64 -o init.o init.S
ld -o init d/init.o
cd d
find . | cpio -o -H newc | gzip > ../rootfs.cpio.gz
ROOTFS_PATH="$(pwd)/../rootfs.cpio.gz"
```

This creates a filesystem with our hello world at `/init`, which is the first userland program that the kernel will run. We could also have added more files to `d/` and they would be accessible from the `/init` program when the kernel runs.

Then `cd` into the Linux kernel tree, build is as usual, and run it in QEMU:

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git
cd linux
git checkout v4.9
make mrproper
make defconfig
make -j"$(nproc)"
qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel arch/x86/boot/bzImage -initrd "$ROOTFS_PATH"
```

And you should see a line:

```
FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR
```

on the emulator screen! Note that it is not the last line, so you have to look a bit further up.

You can also use C programs if you link them statically:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    printf("FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR\n");
    sleep(0xFFFFFFFF);
    return 0;
}
```

with:

```
gcc -static init.c -o init
```

You can run on real hardware with a USB on `/dev/sdX` and:

```
make isoimage FDINITRD="$ROOTFS_PATH"
sudo dd if=arch/x86/boot/image.iso of=/dev/sdX
```

Great source on this subject: http://landley.net/writing/rootfs-howto.html It also explains how to use `gen_initramfs_list.sh`, which is a script from the Linux kernel source tree to help automate the process.

Next step: setup BusyBox so you can interact with the system through a shell. [Buildroot is a great way to do it](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/8815312cad053d0284c4d91bfbf36a1e9ea207af#qemu-buildroot-setup).

Tested on Ubuntu 16.10, QEMU 2.6.1.

Answer (score 2):

You can put your program to [initrd](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/initrd.txt), and then run it from initrd's init.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a boot paramter eg) `init=/bin/bash`

init is the process 1, used by kernel to start user space, which as a few specific duties like reaping children periodical to clean out zombies.  Sounds like you don't even need that.

[Linux Boot parameters you should know](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/10-boot-time-parameters-you-should-know-about-the-linux-kernel.html)